# Pandas sorting dataframe on the basis of other column value

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have this sorted Pandas dataframe `df`.

I use `df = df.sort(col_a,col_b)`

```
 col_a col_b 
   a     6      
   a     7      
   a     8     
   a     11           
   b     5      
   b     10
   b     12
   c     11      
   c     13      
   c     14
```

But I'd sort `df` on the basis of `col_b` min and max value to have in the first place the `col_a` value with min `col_b` value and at the last place the `col_a` value with max `col_b` value :

```
 col_a col_b      
   b     5      
   b     10
   b     12
   a     6      
   a     7      
   a     8      
   a     11      
   c     11      
   c     13      
   c     14
```

Is there a fast way to make this kind of sorting using a pandas fucntion?

**EDIT 1:**

@Primer solution works for a 2 columns `df`.
With this `df`

```
    col_a  col_b  col_c
0     a      6      9
1     a      7      8
2     a      8      7
3     a     11      6
4     b      5      5
5     b     10      4
6     b     12      3
7     c     11      2
8     c     13      1
9     c     14      0
```

return

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

**EDIT 2**

```
d = {'col_a' : ['a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c'],
    'col_b' :[6,7,8,11,12,13,11,13,14],
    'col_c' :[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    }

df = DataFrame(d)
```

return:

```
  col_a  col_b  col_c
0     a      6      9
1     a      7      8
2     a      8      7
3     a     11      6
4     b     12      5
5     b     13      4
6     c     11      3
7     c     13      2
8     c     14      1
```

@Primer Whit this `df` your code doesnt'work because it returns:

```
  col_a  col_b  col_c
0     a      6      9
1     a      7      8
2     a      8      7
3     a     11      6
4     c     11      3
5     c     13      2
6     c     14      1
7     b     12      5
8     b     13      4
```

I need to have

```
  col_a  col_b  col_c
0     a      6      9
1     a      7      8
2     a      8      7
3     a     11      6
4     b     12      5
5     b     13      4
6     c     11      3
7     c     13      2
8     c     14      1
```

because `c` group has the `max(value)=14`,instead your code takes `max(min)` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df['min'] = df.groupby('col_a')['col_b'].transform(lambda x: x.min())
df = df.sort(['min', 'col_a', 'col_b']).reset_index(drop=True).drop('min', 1)
df
```

Which yields:

```
  col_a  col_b
0     b      5
1     b     10
2     b     12
3     a      6
4     a      7
5     a      8
6     a     11
7     c     11
8     c     13
9     c     14
```

EDIT:

I have fixed the code above to make sure `transform` is used on series and not on dataframe (thus avoiding the error).

Works for me returning:

```
  col_a  col_b  col_c
0     b      5      5
1     b     10      4
2     b     12      3
3     a      6      9
4     a      7      8
5     a      8      7
6     a     11      6
7     c     11      2
8     c     13      1
9     c     14      0
```

I guess you could easily turn this into a function to apply on a dataframe inplace.

Comment: real df has more columns then df in example so your code return `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 1 `

Comment: @franco_b i think you're going to need to provide more detail explaining why this solution, which achieves the desired output with your example data, doesn't work on your real data.

Comment: @franco_b ok, but you just accepted this answer, are you all set then?

Comment: Please see edit in the answer to see the fix for this error (since you added more columns `transform` was being applied on a GroupbyDataframe and not on the Series) - all it takes is to pass name of the column after `groupby` to apply `transform` on.

Comment: @Primer I just edit the question to show why your code doesn't work

Comment: @franco_b, based on you question my understanding was that you wanted to see if pandas can be used to handle this kind of tasks. I think I have showed you how it can be used in this case. Along with `min` column you can add `max` one and do sorting based on this value as well. You can, if you need, set sorting rules individually for each column (feel free to see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort))

Comment: Yes Sure. Thanks @Primer. I appreciate your help and I'm tryng to sort the dataframe. With no succes until now, but I think I will do.

Comment: I think if you post the code you are struggling with along with reproducible data and expected result you will get quick help.